# How would I use the jQuery.Deferred Object to wait for an asynchronous function call to complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax, plupload, jquery-deferred

I'm using the [Plupload file uploader](http://www.plupload.com/) within a form. I want to customize it such that when the form is submitted, i.e. when the "Submit" button is clicked, the first thing that happens is the file uploading, followed by the submission of the form.

From what I can tell, and I might be wrong with this, but it seems that the call `uploader.start()` is an asynchronous function call. So at the moment, the uploading will begin and the form will submit before the files are uploaded. The problem is that I don't have control over this function call.

I've recently read about the [new release of jQuery 1.5](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/) and the new [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and it seems like this has the potential to help me solve this problem. Is there a way to wait for the asynchronous function call to finish its work and then continue the execution of the code after the call. So I'm looking for something like the following pseudocode...

```
var uploader = $('#plupload_container').pluploadQueue();

$('#submitButton').click(function() {

   // if there are files to be uploaded, do it
   if (uploader.files.length > 0) {

      // make the call and wait for the uploader to finish
      uploader.start();
      while ( the uploading is not done ) {
         wait for the uploader to finish
      }

      // continue with submission
   }
});
```

Is there a way to "wait" for `uploader.start()` to finish, essentially putting a pause on the click event handler, so that all the files can be uploaded first and then the rest of the click event handler can finish executing? I've tried the following but "done" is printed before the files are done uploading...

```
$.when(uploader.start()).then(function () {
   console.log("done")
});
```

Another useful piece of information... I can bind certain events to this `uploader` object instance, such as "UploadProgress" or "UploadComplete". Can I use the Deferred Object somehow to catch when the "UploadComplete" event fires, for example? Is there an AJAX-y way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that although `uploader.start` does something asynchronous for the code to work, `uploader.start` has to return a jquery `$.deferred` object.

From the latest source on your uploader plugin:

```
/**
 * Starts uploading the queued files.
 *
 * @method start
 */
start : function() {
    if (this.state != plupload.STARTED) {
        this.state = plupload.STARTED;
        this.trigger("StateChanged");
        uploadNext.call(this);
    }
},
```

So it doesn't return a deferred object. Instead in the `uploadNext` function there is this line of code:

`this.trigger("UploadComplete", files);`

So we simply have to bind to your uploader,

```
uploader.bind("UploadComplete", function(files) {
    // your code
});
```

I've never used that plugin but this [should](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html) work. Good luck.

If you must use deferreds then you can always something like this pseudocode:

```
var uploader = $('#plupload_container').pluploadQueue();
var def = $.Deferred();
uploader.bind("UploadComplete", function(files) {
    def.resolve(files);
});
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
   if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
      uploader.start();

      def.done(function(files) {
          def = $.Deferred(); // reset the deferred object.
          // rest of your click handler.
      });

   }
});
```

Comment: @Raynos... thank you for the reply. This all looks great, I hadn't even thought about changing the source code around but that is a great idea! I'll try this out when I'm back in the office and let you know what happens.

Comment: @hristo im not suggesting you change the source code. I'm suggesting you use the events. And if you must you can combine the events with deferred objects. The thing about using 3rd party libraries is not changing their source code. This way you can rely on new releases of their code to fix bugs and bring improvements

Comment: @Raynos... you make a good point. So I read through your example and it looks good. I'll try that out but I have a question... would your example with the Deferred object pause the `.click()` event handler and continue after the `def.done()` finishes or would it just go through the whole click event? If that is the case, is there a way to call like `event.preventDefault()` to pause the click and then somehow continue it after `def.done()` is done?

Comment: @Hristo yes and no. The code in the `done` function will only execute after it's finsihed. The click handler is not paused. If uploading takes 10 seconds then users have 10 seconds to play with the website until the rest of the click handler code is done. Depending on why you need the click handler paused I can give you a solution.

Comment: I need the click handler to pause because the file uploading is happening within a form... so when the click happens, a form is being submitted. I don't want to form to submit until all of the files are uploaded. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Hristo make sure the form submission happens inside the `.done` function or stop the form from submitting. What you want to do is make the uploading synchronous blocking the entire browser and thats just silly.

Comment: Well... I don't know if you've checked out the Plupload website, but it has a "Start Upload" button, however, I can't use it. My "boss" wants it so that when the user clicks the form "Submit" button, the uploading will start and then the form will continue to submit. So this was the only way I could think of taking care of that. Unless you can think of a way to go around that, how would I resolve my issue, ignoring that it is silly?

Comment: @Hristo make the submit button `type=button` rather then `type=submit` and call `form.submit()` at the end of your `.done` function

Comment: Unfortuanetly, this is an `.aspx` page, so "Submit" button is not a `type=button` rather a `type=image`... I believe the actual code is something like `<asp:LinkButton UpdateImage="image/btn_update.png"` or something like that.

Comment: @Hristo then rip out the link button and replace it with an image which you can click on. Make it styled the same using css and manually call `form.submit()`

Comment: Fyi, it's `Deferred`, not `Deffered`

Answer (score 3):

In the context of an imaginary upload session:

```
var files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"];
```

These are the files we would like to upload. Let's assemble another array that has a deferred object for each upload:

```
var uploads = files.map(upload_one);
```

We call $.when() with this array of deferred objects and we also specify what to do after each upload, when anything fails and when everything is done completely:

```
$.when(uploads)
  .progress(function() {
    // report to user, step progress bar, etc
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // display error
  })
  .done(function() {
    // all uploads finished, do stuff
  });
```

This is the work function for each individual upload. It returns the *deferred* object and also calls the success or error functions in response to the individual upload:

```
function upload_one(file) {
  var deferred = new $.Deferred();
  // start upload

  // if finished:
  deferred.notify();
  deferred.resolve();

  // if failed:
  deferred.reject();

  return deferred;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  The point of jquery's new deferred in the ajax api is to allow your code to wait for other asynchronous code.

If you have multiple asynchronous calls that depend on each other, deferred will allow you to perform some action once they all complete.  That same idea applies here.